# Java Exceptions error when trying to execute .jar on Debian Jessie

Tags: java, linux, debian

A teacher of mine created a program on java around 2005, he has always used MacOS. He sent the `.jar` to me and a classmate, both linux (me Debian 8 and him Ubuntu) and we can't execute the program because it returns a lot of exceptions.

At first I thought it could have been because the program was too old but my teacher can run it in his 1 year old updated mac perfectly fine.

Checked and Debian comes with OpenJDK as default. Havent installed anything, is there anything I should be installing for it to run?

PS: if I double click the `.jar` I can see the folders.

The exceptions are:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2866)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1676)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 18 more
```

I don't know anything about java so please if you can try to be as basic as you can. I am also new to Debian, so I really don't know if there's a package missing from the default installation.

Edit:

The `MANIFEST.MF` file is

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
Created-By: 1.6.0_24-b07-334-10M3326 (Apple Inc.)
Class-Path: lib/Jama-1.0.2-ed.jar lib/jfreechart-1.0.6.jar lib/ant.jar
lib/jcommon-1.0.10.jar
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: com.cmcweb.electronicstructure.CompleteDOSPlotter
```

Comment: which version of Java do you have ? This error simply means that you do not have java library on your classpath. This means missing JAR files containing JFreeChart. http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/download.html

Comment: post manifest file of this jar. Open it in winZip or another program that supports zip extension and find a file under meta-inf/manifest.mf.

Comment: My version is `java version "1.7.0_111"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.7) (7u111-2.6.7-2~deb8u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.111-b01, mixed mode)
`. Installed JFreeChart and it still doesnt work, had to install `ant` and then `openjdk-7-jdk`  to be able to install it.

Comment: I am sorry Dominik but I don't understand what you said. What can/should I do with the `MANIFEST.MF` file?

Comment: A Jar file is a zip archive in fact. Open the jar that Your teacher created in WinZip, unzip it, find manifest.mf file (open in notepad) and post the content of it here (edit your question). This will help us figure out what this jar depends on.

Comment: I don't think he'd like the contents of it out there since it's a program to analyze the data gathered from running a simulations prograsm. It's his intellectual property and he wouldnt like it out there. Is the `MANIFEST.MF ` file all the code or does it only show the libraries required?

Comment: it contains the name of the main class and a classpath. If you don't want to share it just compare the value of classpath property with the classpath that you got from teacher.

Comment: I updated the question with file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have all jars with the version from the manifest file downloaded in a lib directory. Lib directory should be placed in the same directory as your jar, the names of dependency jars should be exactly the same as these from classpath in manifest.

So in your case, it may not work with the newest JFreeChart version. You need to find and download version 1.0.6

Comment: Should I have those jars placed in `/usr /lib`, is that what you are saying?

Comment: if your main jar is in /usr directory then yes. In general in /your_jar_location/lib

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Is it like that for every program you want to execute? Meaning that you need the jars in the same directory, or could I add the directories it needs somewhere else so that I don't have to put them on the same folder?

Answer (score 2):

You have to download JFreeChart.jar libary (http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjfreechartjar.htm)  because your teacher didn't include external classes in his jar file.

Put JFreeChart.jar into /your_linux_path/jre/lib/ext folder and after that it should works.

P.S. The same you have to do with Jama.jar and jcommon.jar

Comment: Already installed that. What would the path you are reffering be? found something that said java in `/usr/bin` but haven't been able to find something that says `/jre/` anhywhere I have looked. My lib directory is `/usr/lib` and there there is no `ext` folder there.

Comment: Yeah it's possible that you don't have ext folder. You have to create it.

Comment: So your JRE path is /usr/bin/java/jre?

Comment: No, whatever is called java there it's not a directory. So you say I should put all jars needed in  ` /usr/lib/ext `?

Comment: no. $ which java 
should give you something like

/usr/bin/java

Comment: But maybe you have another path. Just type which java in linux terminal and you find out where yours java path

Comment: Is there any results?

Comment: Typing java didnt return any directory. I was able to execute it by doing what the other comment said, finding the old jars of the things libraries .mf called for and putting them in a folder called lib in the directory where it is being executed. Thanks though, I will research where the `/jre/` folder is and will see if its better to have those libraries there

Comment: The file `/usr/bin/java` will be a symlink. Use `ls -l /usr/bin/java` to see where it points. Fair chance that it will point to another symlink, use `ls -l` to see where it points and it will probably be something like `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-blah/` and there will be a `/lib` directory there.